# Does this sequence converge to zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n,k) = 0$.

Is it then true, that $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f(n,k)}{k!}$ converges to zero for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not.  For instance, take
$$
f(n,k)=\frac{k!}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f(n,k)}{k!}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
but for any fixed $k$ we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k!}{\sqrt{n}}=0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(n,k)=\frac{k!}{n+1}$ then clearly that $f$ verify the hypothesis however

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f(n,k)}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{n+1}=1\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1\ne0$$